# PHP Prepared statement with dynamic query

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I correctly use bind_param() without failing? I consistently encounter 'Error binding parameters:'

When a SQL query is required, I have previously set up every parameter; otherwise, none will be set. Then, I use array in bind_param(). I anticipate receiving accurate results without any mistakes.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
include ('config.php');

$id_selection = $_POST['id'];
$type_selection = $_POST['type'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$source = $_POST['source'];
$date_type = $_POST['date_type'];
$date1 = strtr($_POST['date1'], '/', '-');
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date1));
$date2 = strtr($_POST['date2'], '/', '-');
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));

$parts = [];
$params = [];
$btypes = []; //bind type

$parts[] = "SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM tablea
    WHERE ";

if ($type_selection == 'ALL') {
    if($bilbpk>0) {
        $parts[] = "kod_mainhq IN (".implode(',', array_map('intval', $myhqlist)).")";
    } else {
        $parts[] = "kod_mainhq NOT IN (0) AND type_mainhq IN ('MAIN HQ') AND active_mainhq IN (1) ";
    }
} else if ($type_selection == 'kem') {
$parts[] = " kod_mainhq =? ";
$params[] = &$id_selection;
$btypes[] = 'i';
} else if ($type_selection == 'agn') {
$parts[] = " kod_subhq = ? ";
$params[] = &$id_selection;
$btypes[] = 'i';
} else if ($type_selection == 'ptj') {
$parts[] = " kod_subshq = ? ";
$params[] = &$id_selection;
$btypes[] = 'i';
} else {
$parts[] = " kod_subshq = ? ";
$params[] = &$id_selection;
$btypes[] = 'i';
}

if ($category == 'ALLCATEGORIES') {
        $parts[] = " ";
}else{
        $parts[] = " AND (kod_category= ?) ";
        $params[] = &$category;
        $btypes[] = 'i';
}

if ($source == 'ALLSOURCE') {
        $parts[] = " ";
}else{
        $parts[] = " AND (source_data= ?) ";
        $params[] = &$source;
        $btypes[] = 'i';
}

if ($date_type == "all") {
    $parts[] = " AND (date_acq >=? AND date_acq <=?) ";
    $params[] = &$date1;
    $params[] = &$date2;
    $btypes[] = 's';
    $btypes[] = 's';
} else if ($date_type == "req") {
    $parts[] = " AND date_request >=? AND date_request <=? ";
    $params[] = &$date1;
    $params[] = &$date2;
    $btypes[] = 's';
    $btypes[] = 's';
} else if ($date_type == "pzst") {
    $parts[] = " AND date_pst >=? AND date_pst <=? ";
    $params[] = &$date1;
    $params[] = &$date2;
    $btypes[] = 's';
    $btypes[] = 's';
} else {
    $parts[] = " ";
}

$parts[] = " AND kod_mainhq NOT IN (0) AND type_mainhq IN ('MAIN HQ') AND active_mainhq IN (1)
             AND kod_mainhq IN (SELECT ot_id FROM organization_tree WHERE ot_type='MAIN HQ' AND ot_status=1)
             ORDER BY date_acq DESC";

$sqlstrs = implode("\n", $parts);
$xbtypes = implode('', $btypes); //extract bind types

$stmt = $con->prepare($sqlstrs);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die('Error preparing statement: ' . $con->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param($xbtypes, ...$params);
if (!$success) {
    die('Error binding parameters: ' . $stmt->error);
}
$stmt->execute();
if (!$success) {
    die('Error executing statement: ' . $stmt->error);
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>field1</td>";
      echo "<td>field2</td>";
      echo "<td>field3</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: Is there not a more detailed message after the "Error binding parameters: " bit? There should be more info available about why it failed. Also, have you debugged your code to examine the final SQL string, and checked the number of parameter placeholders in there against the number of items in $params, and the number of items in $btypes, and that all the type strings match the input values? I don't get a sense of any real investigation happening. We can't see the data you're using, or easily run your code without access to your database, so to get help you first need to do proper investigations

Comment: umm well, this error is caused by a very silly typo (and lack of proper error reporting). Add error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top and see what PHP would say. Then remove EVERY `if .. die()` condition from the code

Comment: The error doesn't come from MySQL or mysqli. You created the error with `if (!$success) {`. Remove this useless `if` statement and the "error" will go away.